# Save Tuple Or Equivalent to Session

Tags: php, session, tuples, session-variables

I have to store an array of unique items to the $_SESSION when the user has selected an item. Each item doesn't have a unique ID, I'm using a composite of itemName and storeID. What would be an appropriate method to store each tuple (or similar object/fixed array) to an array in the Session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make foreach store an array which contains all the selected items from this store. E.g:

```
$_SESSION['items'] = array(
                       "store1" => array("item1", "item2",...),
                       "store2" => array("item1", "item2",...),
                       ...
);
```